# How can I create a list of all possible states of a system

Tags: python-3.x

Hey so I'm currently writing a bit of python code to describe some interesting quantum mechanics and I wanted to know is there away I can easily create a piece of code which will create a list of all possible states.

So I have tried using the iterabletools module, I used this;

Basis_vecs = list(it.combinations_with_replacement('01',r=4))

But it gave me a list of [('0', '0', '0', '0'), ('0', '0', '0', '1'), ('0', '0', '1', '1'), ('0', '1', '1', '1'), ('1', '1', '1', '1')] and I need a list like [('0', '0', '0', '0'), ('0', '0', '0', '1'),('0', '0','1','0'),('0', '1','0', '0'),( '1','0', '0','0'), ('0', '0', '1', '1'),('0', '1', '0', '1'),('1', '0', '0', '1'),('0', '1', '1', '0'),('1', '0', '1', '0'), ('0', '1', '1', '1'), ('1', '1', '0', '1'),('1', '1', '1', '0') ('1', '1', '1', '1')].

I actually need to add an additional constraint later, but I think I can manage that part. Still getting used to using Python. Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

you are looking for [`product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from itertools import product

states = list(product(range(2), repeat=4))
print(states)
# [(0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1, 1), 
#  (0, 1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0, 1), (0, 1, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1, 1),
#  (1, 0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0, 1), (1, 0, 1, 0), (1, 0, 1, 1),
#  (1, 1, 0, 0), (1, 1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1, 1)]
```

where i used integers to represent the base states (therefore the `range(2)`. if you prefer strings you can replace that by `"01"`).

maybe this may be interesting for you: http://qutip.org/

Comment: reputation lower than 15, sorry bud